# Override prometheus.yaml in kube-stack-prometheus

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I'm new to Prometheus, we are trying to override the prometheus.yaml file of our Prometheus via helm chart kube-prometheus-stack

We added configMaps and metricRelabels under service monitor in helm values.yaml but no luck. The configuration does not update to what we have changed. Is there any way we can configure it to update the Prometheus scrape config file?

Comment: have you tried updating the configuration after deploying it?

Comment: are you referring to scrape configs? Did you look into https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/fff784c2439fc64e7afe7a308b82ac155e53827d/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2330 which might be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to override it under values in Kube Prometheus Stack in application config.